# Apply Timezone to all dates in a site

Tags: php, html

On my website, i am working a lot with date and time and I want every registration that is done to be in my time zone. I got this code `<?php date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos'); ?>` from php documentation but I don't really know how and where to apply it that will make it apply to all dates in my site

Comment: You should set it in the php.ini file.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this in header.php (if include in all your pages) or in configuration mysql.

And yes, this (if applied correctly) change all dates in your website

Comment: Yes Davide is true. If i were you, i would apply this code into conf.php (mysql connect). This is the best way. I use like this or i use it in my functions.php (required for all pages).

Comment: Thanks. I added it to my connection file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better at your page header so it can apply to your entire site

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the PHP timezone globally on your server there is only one true way to do it and you will only have to edit one file, the php.ini file. Look for something similar to the following section:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=America/Chicago
```

And set the value of `date.timezone` to one of the [accepted timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) available for PHP. Once done, you must restart your webserver for the changes to take effect.